# TabActivity won't change language

Tags: android

I have problem. 
I have TabActivity with intent tabs.
In my application user can change language in preference settings.
When user change language and application go back to my TabActivity doing this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
    case 1:
        finish();
        startActivity(getIntent());
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

This code run perfectly, because all text is in changed language.

Problem occur, when i restart application. Some texts are not in proper language (are in system default). When i open preference screen once again and back to my TabActivity, texts are all translated.

How can i translate all texts after restart application?
Why when i first run application not all texts are in proper language?

Im sorry for my English, i hope u understand what i mean and help me. Thank you.

This is code from preferenceActivity when saving:

```
    String lang = preferences.getString("Language", "");
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(lang))
          config.locale = new Locale(lang);
        else
          config.locale = Locale.getDefault();
    Locale.setDefault(new Locale(lang));
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
```

tabActivity:

```
public class PlanActivity extends TabActivity {

SharedPreferences preferences;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTitle(R.string.app_name);

    preferences = getSharedPreferences(Constans.PREF, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    edytor = preferences.edit();

    String lang = preferences.getString("Language", "en");
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(lang))
        config.locale = new Locale(lang);
    else
        config.locale = Locale.getDefault();

    Locale.setDefault(new Locale(lang));
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);

     setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
......... more
```

And this code is not working properly. I have to go to settings and go back to tabActivity for refresh texts

Answer (score 0):

Are you correctly saving the changes to the `SharedPreferences` object? The code you provide does not show you using a [SharedPreferences.Editor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html) to save your changes.

EDIT: ensure that the preference file you're saving to in your preference Activity is the same one you're opening in your Tab activity (`preferences = getSharedPreferences(Constans.PREF, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);`). If your tab activity does not find the preferences you're sure you saved in the preference activity then either your save code is not being called (either use a break point or a log statement to verify) or you are saving to the wrong file.

Comment: Yes. I saving correctly: 
`private void setPreferences(){
  SharedPreferences.Editor edytor = preferences.edit();
  edytor.putString("Language", listLanguage.getValue());
  edytor.commit();
 }`

`@Override
 protected void onPause() {
  super.onPause();
  setPreferences();`

Comment: I think i saving correctly and it is the same file. I think that because tabs labels are translatet what i want, but content not. When i go to the preference screen and go back to TabActivity, all texts are correctly.